# Anyone tried Singapore airlines Premium Economy class ? How is it different from economy class?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, singapore-airlines

Apart from the advertised features (Wide, Comfortable Seats, Additional Kris flyer miles and book the cook food menu) what are the other benefits / perks while flying in the new Singapore airlines premium economy class? Is there any considerable difference between A380 Premium economy and with the other ones ?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

The advertised features are all listed here, and you've already listed the important ones:

[SIA Premium Economy](https://siapremiumeconomy.com/)

[Per AusBT](http://www.ausbt.com.au/review-singapore-airlines-premium-economy-seats), the A380 seat (19.5") is one inch wider than the B777-300ER version (18.5").  Seat pitch (38") and all other seat features are otherwise identical.